# How to extend life time context of marker in fixture (pytest)?

Tags: pytest

I have this code for tests:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _check(request, monkeypatch):
    marker = request.node.get_marker('check')
    if marker:
        monkeypatch.setattr('collections.Counter', 'patched')


@pytest.mark.check()
def test_1():
    import collections
    assert collections.Counter == 'patched'  # fine


@pytest.mark.check()
@pytest.fixture()
def set_mark():
    pass


def test_2(set_mark):
    import collections
    assert collections.Counter == 'patched'  # broken
```

test_1 works fine, but test_2 breaks down. I want my marker, placed in the fixture, to work in the test.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Online version - https://repl.it/@MyGodIsHe/ImmaculateArcticLinuxkernel

Comment: Afaik you can't mark fixtures, only test functions.

Comment: @hoefling oh, it was worth a try, thanks